# How can I filter rows in table with Angular?

Tags: angular

So I'm using angular to display some stored information from my database. 
I want to show in my table just the rows that have specific information. For example, show only the rows that have the status Accepted.

```
       <div class="container" >
         <div class="row">

           <table class="table table-dark">
                <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>Boat type</th>
              <th>Service</th>
              <th>Boat Location</th>
              <th>Job type</th>
              <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
          </thead>   
          <tbody>
           <tr *ngFor="let boat of boats" >
           <td>{{ boat.boatType }}</td>
           <td>{{ boat.service }}</td>
           <td>{{ boat.location }}</td>
           <td>{{ boat.jobType }}</td>
           <td>{{ boat.status }}</td>


         </tr>


        </tbody>
      </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to change the `this.boats` array and just not display some rows in the view:

```
       <div class="container" >
         <div class="row">

           <table class="table table-dark">
                <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>Boat type</th>
              <th>Service</th>
              <th>Boat Location</th>
              <th>Job type</th>
              <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
          </thead>   
          <tbody>
           <tr *ngFor="let boat of boats" >
           <td *ngIf="boat.status === 'Accepted'">{{ boat.boatType }}</td>
           <td *ngIf="boat.status === 'Accepted'">{{ boat.service }}</td>
           <td *ngIf="boat.status === 'Accepted'">{{ boat.location }}</td>
           <td *ngIf="boat.status === 'Accepted'">{{ boat.jobType }}</td>
           <td *ngIf="boat.status === 'Accepted'">{{ boat.status }}</td>

         </tr>


        </tbody>
      </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: A `div` not a valid tag within a `table`, so it's technically not valid html

Comment: Indeed, fixed for a verbose answer, but functional. Many thanks.

Answer (score 6):

In the `.ts` file, you can do:

```
this.boats = this.boats.filter((boat) => boat.status === 'Accepted')
```

This will remove any items that don't have that status

Answer (score 4):

In your case, you can use **[angular pipe](https://angular.io/guide/pipes)**.

For example, you want to filter your array inside of `ngfor`

First, you define your pipe like this

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'exampleFilter'})

export class ExamplePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(arr) {
    return arr.filter((boat) => boat.status === 'Accepted');
  }
}
```

Then import it into your module [example: AppModule.ts] like this

```
import { ExamplePipe } from './examplePipe.pipe'; // import our pipe here

@NgModule({
  ...
  declarations: [ ... , ExamplePipe ], // include example pipe here
  ...
})

export class AppModule { }
```

Then you can use this like this

```
<tr *ngFor="let boat of boats | exampleFilter" >
  <td>{{ boat.boatType }}</td>
  <td>{{ boat.service }}</td>
  <td>{{ boat.location }}</td>
  <td>{{ boat.jobType }}</td>
  <td>{{ boat.status }}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Nice input, shouldn't it be `import { ExamplePipe } from '...'` ?

Comment: You're right I've changed it, thanks. @Learningisamess

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe filter array with pipe is consider a bad practices , why there is no filter pipe in angular ?

Comment: I don't think it's a bad practice, the Angular pipe can do much more than just filtering or sorting.

Answer (score 4):

You can filter the rows in the template by using an `ng-container` for the `ngFor` loop, and by applying an `ngIf` condition on the `tr` elements. Please note that the `ng-container` itself is not rendered in the HTML output.

```
<tbody>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let boat of boats" >
    <tr *ngIf="boat.status === 'Accepted'">
      <td>{{ boat.boatType }}</td>
      <td>{{ boat.service }}</td>
      <td>{{ boat.location }}</td>
      <td>{{ boat.jobType }}</td>
      <td>{{ boat.status }}</td>
    </tr>
  </ng-container>
</tbody>
```

See [**this stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eaqqnc) for a demo.